# How can I copy live UIView's into a new UIView?

Tags: ios4, uiview, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller, uilabel

I have 6 UIView's (UILabel's and UIImageView's) laid out in a NIB for display during regular app use.  The contents of the labels and the image views change dynamically during use.

At a certain point in app functioning, I want to take those views -- with the contents they have at that moment -- and put them into a new UIView, where I can slightly rearrange them and change the text in one of the UILabel's.  So I don't want pointers to the original UIView's -- I want copies that I can play with.  How can I get them?

Purpose here is to create an overlayView for when the user takes a picture.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a programmatic way to do this.  Instead, I created a new UIView in my NIB (pretty much copying, pasting, and rearranging the UILabel's and UIImageView's I needed) and hooked up new IBOutlets for the UIView and all its subviews.  Then when I need to display the camera overlay, I set the contents of the UILabel's and UIImageView's to match the contents of the source views.  It actually works very well.